# is there function for get all keys from tuple list when key is not atom?

Tags: elixir

I want to get all keys from a tuple list, but module `Keyword` requires the key should be atom, otherwise, it throw error.

Now I use a loop to solve it, and maybe it is not necessary if it already exists. Can it be simplified?

```
iex(4)> a = [{{1,0,0},1},{{1,0,1},2}]
[{{1, 0, 0}, 1}, {{1, 0, 1}, 2}]
iex(5)> Enum.map(a,fn {key,_} -> key end)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you have is perfectly fine and very common.

You could make it slightly briefer with [`elem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2) and using function capture syntax, but that's just personal preference:

```elixir
Enum.map(a, &elem(&1, 0))
```

You could also use a comprehension:

```elixir
iex> for {key, _value} <- a, do: key
[{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}]
```

If you have nested data, [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#elem/2) might be useful, but it's probably overkill in this case.

```elixir
iex> get_in(a, [Access.all(), Access.elem(0)])
[{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it is the first time to use `&` `get_in` .